# How to Define and Implement (Single-Writer) K-Atomic Snapshot Object?

Tags: reference-request, dc.distributed-comp

I am trying to motivate, define, and implement $K$-atomic snapshot object. To this aim, I first give some basic definitions on atomic snapshot object and $K$-atomic object. Then, I will give my understanding of $K$-atomic snapshot object and present my problems.

**Atomic Snapshot Object:**

In the paper ["Atomic Snapshots of Shared Memory"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=153724.153741), the authors consider atomic snapshot objects —— shared objects partitioned into segments. For the **single-writer atomic snapshot object**, each segment belongs to a different processor and is written separately, but all segments can be read at once by any processor.

> The sequence specification of an atomic snapshot object provides two kinds of operations for each user $i, 0 \le i \le n-1$:
>
> - A $scan_i$ invocation whose response is $return_i(V)$, where $V$ is an $n$-element vector called a *view* with a value for each segment, and
> - An $update_i(d)$ invocation whose response is $ack_i$, where $d$ is the data to be written to $p_i's$ segment.
>
> A sequence of $scan$ and $update$ operations satisfies the *atomic snapshot semantics* means that, for each $V$ returned by a $scan$ operation, $V[i]$ equals the value written by the latest preceding $update_i$ operation, for all $i$.

**$K$-Atomic Object:**

In the paper [On the Availability of Non-strict Quorum Systems](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lorenzo/papers/disc05.pdf), $K$-atomic object is introduced. Different from the classical **atomic object** (see [Sharing Memory Robustly in Message-Passing Systems](http://www.cse.huji.ac.il/course/2004/dist/p124-attiya.pdf)), in a system with $K$-atomic semantics,

> there exists an order of the operations that is consistent with real time order and such that the values returned by a read operation is equal to *one of the values written by the last $K$* preceding writes in the order.

**Problem 1: How to Define $K$-Atomic Snapshot Object?**

$K$-atomic object is a relaxation (or a generalization) of classical atomic object, which is actually $1$-atomic object.

So based on the two concepts of $K$-atomic object and atomic snapshot object, can we define, in a reasonable manner, the $K$-atomic snapshot object?

*One possible trial is to relax the timeliness of the snapshot:*

> A sequence of $scan$ and $update$ operations satisfies the *$K$-atomic snapshot semantics* means that, for each $V$ returned by a $scan$ operation,
>
> - $V[i]$ equals one of the values written by the last $K$ preceding $update_{i}$s, for all $i$, and
> - there exists some time before the $scan$ operation at which $V[i]$ equals the value written by its latest preceding $update_{i}$, for all $i$.

**Problem 2: Do you know or can you figure out some other reasonable definitions of $K$-atomic snapshot object?**

Any comments, any suggestions, and any related literature references are welcomed.
Also, I appreciate the idea of implementation of the $K$-atomic snapshot object defined above myself (if you think it is OK).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **Problem 1**: I think the first part of the definition is fine. 
The second item (about the time before $scan$) is not clear to me; More specifically, the order of quatifiers: is it $\exists time: \forall i$ or $\forall i: \exists time$ ? I guess the first, because in the second I don't see why it is necessary. But definitions should not need guessing ;-)

Regarding **Problem 2**: In principle there is two ways of looking at $K$. You can consider the last $K$ updates on a per item level or the last $K$ updates globally. The other choice is (already mentioned above) whether to require a point in time when the memory actually had the value returned by $scan$ (the $\exists time: \forall i$ case above) or whether not to require such a point.

A **general** comment: What happens when every process just updates $K$ times and scans until two scans are equal. Wouldn't that (trivially) implement ($1$-)atomic snapshot memory? If that is the case then the whole idea of $K$-atomic snapshpot memory could be hard to sell.

Comment: Regarding **Comment 1:** it is $\exists time : \forall i$. Regarding **Comment 2:** I agree with you that there is a possible definition in which no a time point when the memory actually had the value returned by $scan$ exists. Actually, [ZooKeeper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix10/tech/full_papers/Hunt.pdf) implements it and calls it _fuzzy snapshot_. However, theoretically, I am more interested in the definition which requires such points. AndI think both its computational power and implementations will be a challenge.

Comment: **Regarding general comment:** Of course, we can always implement (1-)atomic snapshot objects. However, maybe weaker versions are enough sometimes (e.g., as checkpoints for recovery). If we can implement $K-$atomic snapshot objects more efficiently, it is maybe useful. As for its computational power, can we relate it to $K-$mutual exclusion or $K-$set agreement (just my guess)? What do you think of it?